# Zend Translate Poedit and the Translation Context

Tags: translate, zend-translate

is there a way to use the "context" or "msgctxt" in Zend_Translate when I call the method $translator->translate('My String') ?

I need to classify the item to be translated to a specific context for instance:

- Customer Administration
- Shopping Cart
- Order Administration

I need to use the contexts to solve ambiguities between the translation items.

At the moment I am using the PoEdit software and Zend_Translate to translate my project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was searching this too, and it would seem that `Zend_Translate` does **not** support translation context.

You could try to extend the main `Zend_Translate` class and implement the translation context as some kind of prefix that is automatically used together with the sentence or terms to be translated, for example:

```
$translate->translate($context, $sentence);
```

would be internally managed as

```
parent::translate("$context|$sentence");
```

and

```
$translate->translate($context, array($singular, $plural, $num));
```

would be

```
parent::translate(array("$context|$singular", "$context|$plural", $num));
```

but this would require to have the string with the prefixed `$context` in your translation sources.

Comment: Salve Matteo, are you sure?

Comment: I am pretty sure, what you can do is make sure to use some kind of prefix in your messages so that they will be guaranteed to be different for each context.

Comment: it's an idea, but you will lose the normal way to use of the Zend_Translate. maybe can we extend the class?

Comment: unfortunatelly I have to handle a big project and it is really difficult handle/change all the translation items.

Comment: Then you'll have to look elsewhere.. Perhaps ZF2?